# Collect Data from User (CDFU) Workflow does not work

Tags: 2010, workflow, sharepoint-designer

I am trying to use the "Collect Data From User" (CDFU) workflow action to collect data from users and then use the "update list item" action to use the data entered by the user and update a field in the current list item.

The CDFU action creates a new task for collecting the data, but once it is "completed" by the user to whom it is assigned, the workflow doesn't move further.

The task status shows "completed" but the workflow status keeps showing "in progress" - it neither gives any error nor does it update the list item.

Any idea what's going wrong here?

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of the the workflow steps?

Comment: What does the workflow history say?

Comment: The workflow status keeps showing "in progress".

Comment: Not just the status - check the workflow history

Comment: Or, any steps to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Can you check your "Workflow" timer job status (and last execute time) under "Monitoring" in Central Administration? If this isn't working properly, any workflows that rely on external input will never progress past this point.

Comment: There are no errors shown in "Monitoring" in Central Administration

Comment: I was hoping there was a solution posted here as I just hit this same problem. CDFU worked great for 6 months, but then suddenly stopped working. Looking at the Task list, it shows the task as "Not started" yet also includes the data collected from the user. The user selected complete task. Created new workflow to mirror desired function, that workflow won't flow through either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is simply no answer to your question.

I have created simple workflow with just two steps: `CDFU` and `Update list item`. I have played with it for hour or so doing everything I could think of (renaming and deleting fields,  changing task and item during workflow, setting different permissions etc). I was unable to reproduce behavior you are experiencing. My workflow ended either with error or with status completed.

My little experiment leads only to one conclusion: Your problem is too localized and you are probably using much more complex workflow then my simple 2-step. But even if you provide more info I doubt that anyone can easily offer some real solution.

So what can you do?

- Republish your workflow and check it again
- Add Log to history list activity after each step (just log 'Step1', 'Step2' ...) and then look at history to determine exact place where your workflow is stuck
- Try to remove all additional activities (one by one) you may have between CDFU and Update and then test workflow again
- Remove all other customizations you may have on list (eg List Item Event Receivers) and test your workflow ...  again
- Publish your workflow on different list or better on different site and test it there
- Build simple 2-step workflow (CDFU - Update) and test it on original list
- Completely recreate your workflow under different name and test it on original list

And after you try all of the above post your findings so maybe someone can help you.

Edited nothing: request is in comments.

Comment: Thanks Vedran, Looks like I will take some time to follow the steps you have listed. Will surely revert back once I have tried it.

Comment: accepted??? something was helpful?

Comment: Yes, it helped to find the error, but my workflow is too complex so I will have to recreate it. By mistake, I down voted your reply... can you please edit something in it so that I can up vote it again.

Comment: I edited my answer. Good to hear you managed to solve your problem.